# SQL DATETIME query

Tags: mysql, datetime, format

Hi im trying to compare two dates in MySQL via a query, one is a date when an article was first posted and the second date is for when it should be removed by the query (after 365 days, ran by a cron task every 30 minutes.), below is my SQL query

```
DELETE FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'business' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date_gmt) > 2
```

My date is held in the database in this format `2011-05-26 13:10:56` so my question is will the DATETIME query honour the exact date **and time** or when cron is ran at the 365th day delete the article even if there are still `13:10:56` left before it is actually 365 days old?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query, as written, will delete any posts older than 2 days--not 365.

But the answer to your question is easy to test:

```
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2011-01-01 00:10:00','2011-01-01 00:00:00');
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| DATEDIFF('2011-01-01 00:10:00','2011-01-01 00:00:00') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                     0 | 
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, DATEDIFF() returns only whole days, as an integer. A similar test with '2011-01-01 23:59:59' as the first date will also yield 0.

So the short answer to your question is "Yes, it honors the date and time, down to the second."

Comment: Ahhh flimzy i see you have a sharp eye for detail (thats a c&p from a test drive i have running) the end result will be 365 days, so i thank you for taking the time to answer my question and will mark it as answered.best regards Martin

Comment: Also note, that by saying > 365, you're really deleting posts _older_ than 365 days--in other words "366 days or older".  You might want to say >= 365, if you want to delete things exactly 365 days after they are posted.  Although I suspect it matters little if your posts stick around for one more day before they get the axe :)

Comment: Actually flimzy that is important as i have an echoe'd call via php from MySql on the article page that shows when the post will expire (visible to the article owner only), thanks for the tip. tis appreciated